# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'userCoords' of null

Tags: typescript, google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

Getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'userCoords' of null error when trying to assign latlng object to a variable

Home.page.ts file

```
 export class HomePage {
  map: GoogleMap;
  userCoords : any ;
   constructor() {

     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
     (this.geolocationSuccess,this.geolocationError,{});
    this.loadMap();
     }

 loadMap() {

    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {

           'camera' : {
          target: this.userCoords,
          zoom: 15
  },
  'preferences': {
          'zoom': {
                  'minZoom': 15,
                  'maxZoom': 18
          }
                }
        this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);
      }




     geolocationSuccess  = function(position)
      {
     this.userCoords = {lat: position.coords.latitude,lng:    
   position.coords.longitude}  /////===>getting error here
      }
   geolocationError = function()
  {

   }
}
```

How to assign the value lat and lng to another variable 
i have to tried to define userCoords as object,String and any

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that function is callback and "this" is current functon context. use arrow function insteed to automaticly bind component "this" to the function

```
geolocationSuccess = (position) => {
  this.userCoords = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude, lng:
      position.coords.longitude
  }
}
```